# Parsing error: Unexpected token when trying to write a condition

Tags: reactjs

I tried to write a condition for my own hsx element, but I got an error
Line 11:24:  Parsing error: Unexpected token (11:24)

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Cart.css';

function Cart ({active, setActive, offer}) {
    return (
        <div className={active ? 'cart active' : 'cart'} onClick={() => setActive(false)}>
            <div className="cart__content" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
                <h1 className='cart__content-header'>Ваша корзина</h1>
                <div>
                    {
                        if (offer.length == 0) { //Error here
                            return (
                                <p>Тут пока пусто</p>
                            )
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                <button className='cart__content-button'>Оформить заказ</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an `if` statement inside JSX, you need to use a ternary operator instead:

`{offer.length === 0 ? <p>Тут пока пусто</p> : null}`

Comment: never use && operator in jsx, because if you are fetching data from an api, before it loads up data user will see 0 in the UI, which is very very ugly.